# Two ng-repeat, one affect another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Today I faced a strange problem for me in AngularJS.

In this example I have two ng-repeat in product (two or three images and the same number of colors) and one ng-repeat for pagination (irrelevant in this case I assume).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item-wrapper" ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage]">
  <div class="item">
   <!-- Item image -->
     <div class="item-image">
      <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="desc in item._source.description" ng-show="$first">
        <img class="preview" ng-src="server/{{desc.smallImage.url}}">
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <!-- Item details -->
    <div class="item-details">
     <div class="product-colors">
      <ul class="btn-group pull-right">
       <li ng-repeat="color in item._source.description">
       <img class="color" ng-src="server/{{color.thumbnailImage.url}}" />
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All I wanted to do is that click on one  of colors (img.color) changes corresponding img.preview visibility. In my attempts I was always able to changed every img.preview in whole list, not the one I clicked on.

***MY ATTEMPTS:***

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="desc in item._source.description" ng-show="$index === selectedColor">
<li ng-repeat="color in item._source.description" ng-click="changeColor($index)">
```

**JS (controller)**

```
$scope.changeColor = function(idx) {                
 $scope.selectedColor = idx || 0; //default show always first img.preview from list
};
```

***MY ATTEMPTS #2 (working)***

**HTML**

```
<li><img class="preview" ng-src="server/{{desc[__selected === $index ? __num : 0].smallImage.url}}">
<li ng-repeat="color in item._source.description" ng-click="changeColor($index, key)">
```

**JS (controller)**

```
$scope.changeColor = function(idx, key) {
  $scope.__selected = key;
  $scope.__num = idx;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be quite simple:

Considering `desc` and `color` will be referring to same object as they are of the same source.
So, `desc` and `color` should be identical and setting a property on either of them supposed to reflect on the other.

Make the changes as follow and try, havent tested though:

```
<li ng-repeat="desc in item._source.description" ng-show="item.__selected ? desc==item.__selected : $first">
```

and

```
<li ng-repeat="color in item._source.description">
    <img class="color" ng-src="server/{{color.thumbnailImage.url}}" ng-click="item.__selected = color" />
</li>
```

Comment: Hey code90! Your solution is much better, but it shows second picture next to first. I just want a one picture in item :-(

Comment: Yep :-) When I click second color, second image next to first appears.

Comment: OK. I think this time i got it. Will you give it another try?

Comment: Wonderful! That's exacly what I meant. Thank You! I got the idea to achieve this in other way (edited in MY ATTEMPTS: #2)